# Delete picture prompt in Keynote

Tags: photos, keynote

I am creating Keynote masters and every time I insert a picture it puts an icon on it, helpfully to allow you to insert a photo from your file. It doesn't show up in the final keynote but it is a pain in the neck. How do I delete it?

[image: Screenshot of insert image icon.]

Answer (score 1):

Uncheck ‘Define as Media Placeholder’ in the Style tab of the Format inspector,
or Format → Advanced → Define as Media Placeholder in the menus.

[image]